# I want to set placeholder to textbox using data-* attribute in html using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set placeholder using data-* attribute. I tried with jQuery. but not working. if i use id instead of all input type. its working.

but i want common code to set placeholder for any input text fields in a page.

### html:

```
<p>Login</p>
<input type="text" data-placeholder="Email" id="txtemail" />
<input type="password" data-placeholder="Password" id="txtpass" />
```

### jQuery:

```
foctext = $('input:text').attr("data-placeholder");
$(this).val(foctext);
$(this).focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == foctext) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
$(this).blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val(foctext);
    }
});
```

please write correct solution for this. thank you

Comment: Why are you not using `<input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="txtemail" />`

Comment: Place holder atribute will not work on IE versions prior to 10

Comment: i think this link is showing what you are trying to do. remember HTML5 does this already in most new browsers. Note in the link the ability to add this functionality when its missing.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: Also  setting value in password will not display the text.It will be shown as ******

Comment: But, we should use `placholder` attribute for good browsers and then fallback to js implementation for ie's. He can have the same logic even with `placeholder` as the attribute.

Comment: Why not just set the value to the value you seem to want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can use jQuery .data() selector - read more here - http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).data('placeholder');
    $(this).attr('placeholder', txt);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: sure you need, but the author just asked for a function, so I skipped this part

Comment: You must not skip that part since he is a newbie and it will be diffcult to find the problem..so you must make your answer clear and accurate..

Comment: Point taken. Edited version above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code :

$('input:text').each(function(){
    var placeholder = $(this).data('data-placeholder');
    $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this way,

```
<p>Login</p>
<input type="text" data-placeholder="Email" id="txtemail" />
<input type="text" data-placeholder="Password" id="txtpass" data-type="password" />


$.each($('input:text, input:password'), function(key, value){
    $(this).val($(this).attr("data-placeholder"));
    $(this).focus(function(){
        if($(this).attr("data-placeholder") == $(this).val()){
            if($(this).attr('data-type') == "password"){
                $(this).attr('type', 'password')
            }
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "" ){
            $(this).val($(this).attr("data-placeholder"));
        }
        if($(this).attr("data-placeholder") == $(this).val()){
            $(this).attr('type', 'text')
    } 
    });
});
```

See jsFiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/sakNy/2/